# Custom parameter with file browser in TeamCity runner

Tags: teamcity

When I write a Command Line build step in TeamCity, it has a "working directory" parameter which includes a file-tree browser button that can be clicked to view the directories and files in the checkout directory (via the VCS).

If I extract this step into a meta-runner, the internal runner represents that as the `teamcity.build.workingDir` parameter.  I would like to expose this so that the caller of the meta-runner needs to specify this directory.

I can add a parameter to the meta-runner itself (e.g. `directory`) and pass it down but then this becomes a plain-text entry field and loses the file-tree browser.

Is there some way to mark the custom parameter to also use the file-tree browser, or otherwise "expose" the workingDir directly in such a way that the browser is retained?